# What is the supervisor girl doing in TV show 3%?

Tags: plot-explanation, 3-percent

In the new Netflix original TV show 3%, episode one and two, there is a girl sent by high management to evaluate the current candidate selection process. I noticed this girl occasionally takes a sip from a pen-looking thing. Anyone knows what that is? Given the fictional futuristic story background, I am guessing it is some kind of tobacco or recreational drug?

Edit:

I managed to get a screenshot

[image]

Comment: You mean an [E cigarette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette)? I haven't seen the show, so I'm guessing based on your description. These aren't futuristic, though, they're ubiquitous in the US.

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of it?